# Getting textbox data from a name C# Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

If I have a textbox with the name textbox00 how do I get the data from it by using the name?

Comment: By using the text property.....textbox00.text

Comment: @ChrisCatignani I assume that `textbox00` is a string, and the OP wants to lookup the object reference based on the control name. Though if the OP isn't using string lookup, then you're absolutely correct. (Text is uppercase though)

Comment: @gunr2171...Ah...I was using Akum's Razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netcore-3.1) like this:

```
string ctlToFind = "textbox00";
TextBox tb = Controls.Find(ctlToFind, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tb.Text);
}
```